# How to open broadcast list on WhatsApp from my app?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to create a new broadcast with specific contacts and pre-fill the text. 
How do I do that in android studio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking, preventing downvotes and forwarding to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012), you can create a text message with pre-filled text, but I believe you can't pre-define the contacts to send to